# php: чем плох mysql_query( )?

Tags: php, mysql

В одной из вакансий на позицию junior php среди прочих требований встретил такое: "вы нам подходите, если в вашем коде нет и намека на mysql_query("SELECT * ...."

Чем плох mysql_query( )? Это непрофессионально? Как надо писать "правильно"? Спасибо.

Comment: Прочитайте тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php что написано в предупреждении от разработчиков.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я не знаю, что имелось в виду конкретно на той вакансии, но могу предположить, что принципиальное значение придавалось не столько mysql или mysqli драйверу, и даже не PDO, сколько предпологалось наличие у кандидата знания и опыта работы с какими-либо ORM (а как следствие, хотя бы минимальный опыт с каким-нибудь фреймворком, либо умение подключить интересующий пакет через composer), которые представляют гораздо более высокий уровень абстракции и объектный подход для доступа к данным.

Плохой тон, опять же, не сам mysql_query, а бездумное смешивание логики работы с данными с логикой работы приложения и бизнес-логикой.
Когда в контроллере встречается что-то типа:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

это плохой тон. С использованием ORM, у Вас будет что-то типа:

```
$productMapper = new ProductMapper();
$products = $productMapper->findAll();
```

И такой подход гораздо гибче и человекопонятнее (если правильно его использовать, конечно).

Почитайте про наиболее распространенные ORM для PHP (*Doctrine, Eloquent, Yii\ActiveRecord*), посмотрите как с ними принято работать, хотя бы поверхностно ознакомьтесь с паттернами объектно-реляционного отображения, такими как *Table Gateway, Row Gateway, Active Record, Data Mapper*, и сразите работодателей своим глубоким пониманием сути вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query уже нет в 7 версии.
Используйте PDO или хотябы mysqli_query

Comment: Ну, mysqli - да, это понятно. Но непонятно, почему сам запрос так уж плох... Если я пользуюсь только одной базой данных, и мне не надо переключаться между базами, зачем мне PDO?

Answer (score 1):

это уже плохой тон) начиная с версии пхп 5.6 не рекомендуется использовать, а в пхп 7 вобще убрали. надо юзать pdo